# Error running mongoImport from the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a problem importing a json-file with MongoDB. 
The desired file is in the folder (when I execute the command ls() the file is listed) but the method gives me this error:

> mongoimport --db geo --collection points --file zips.json
>   Wed Mar 19 09:42:49.032 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong.

Greetings, Andre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok,that is pretty stupid. you have to insert the mongoimport --db --coll... in the normal cmd and not in the mongo-shell. then it works without problems

Comment: the is STUPID, 
I had the same issue :), complete Mongo newbie.

Answer (score 1):

You have to say the file type you are importing

```
mongoimport --db geo --collection points --file zips.json --type json
```

Comment: That does not work: > mongoimport --db geo --collection points --file zips.json --type json
Wed Mar 19 10:36:49.865 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Maybe you have an invalid .json file, the `mongoimport` command has no mystery :S

Comment: mongoimport --help
Wed Mar 19 14:29:17.384 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: It seems to me that there is something basic wrong :(